# differences of special characters in regex: .net vs javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex, vb.net

I've got this implementation in javascript:

```
EscapeForRegex = function(input) {
        var specials = ["[", "\\", "^", "$", ".", "|", "?", "*", "+", "(", ")", "{", "}"]
        for (var k in specials) {
            var special = specials[k];
            input = input.replace(new window.RegExp("\\" + special, "g"), "\\" + special);
        }
        return input;
    };
```

however when i compare my implementation to the page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx, i find 2 differences.

1. I've included **]** but the page doesn't do so. is it true that we do not have to include the **]** ? (apparently I'm not doubting that page, but since my implementation is in javascript and not c#/vb..)
2. I've missed out **#**. is the # symbol special in javascript regex?

Comment: Please see "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) I've included ] but the page doesn't do so. is it true that we do not have to include the ] ? (apparently I'm not doubting that page, but since my implementation is in javascript and not c#/vb..)

`]` only has to be escaped inside a character set.  That list is also missing `-` which needs to be escaped inside character sets sometimes.  E.g., to create a character set containing the characters space, dash, and the letter A, you would need to escape the `-` thus: `/[ \-A]/` or move the dash to the side: `/[- A]/`.

Of the characters that you listed above, only `]`, `-`, `^`, and `\\` ever need to be escaped in character sets.  `^` only needs to be escaped inside a character set if it is in the character set and at the beginning.

If you want to include the regular expression text inside the literal form, `/.../` instead of `new RegExp("...")` you also need to escape line terminator characters: codepoint U+000A, U+000D, U+2028, U+2029, and the `/` character when outside a character set.

> 2) I've missed out #. is the # symbol special in javascript regex?

No, `#` is not special in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, your function can be reduced to:

```
function EscapeForRegex(input){
    return input.replace(/[(-.]|[$?[\]\\^|{}]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

which doesn't include `#`, and does include `]` and `-`, as pointed out by Mike Samuel.